# how to begin learning oracle forms and reports?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

i have complete sql and plsql course and , i want to begin learn oracle forms and reports 
so i want to know how to begin and what i need (books , websites ..)

thanks

Comment: excellent question - I can't answer myself since I learned Forms/Reports over 10 years ago at university and I'd be surprised if any uni or college is teaching Forms now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get yourself an install of Oracle Forms that you can use for testing and experimenting.  Forms is part of the Oracle Fusion Middleware product now and requires WebLogic Server to be installed.

Take a look at the Oracle Forms page to get info on how to get a development copy downloaded and installed:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/overview/index-098877.html

The Oracle Fusion Middleware documentation library is a great resource for tutorials and installation guides.  Use it to learn how to install the product and then start working the tutorials:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/middleware.html